# Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку Unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
second = random.choice([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A'])
player_deck = random.choice([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A'])
def func(x):
    if x == 'J' or x == 'Q' or x == 'K':
        x = 10
    elif x == 'A':
        x = 11
func(player_deck)
func(second)
player_deck+=second
print(player_deck)
```

Comment: `second` может кроме цифр содержать и буквы, а вы пытаетесь прибавить его к числу `player_deck+=second`

Comment: У функции `func` нет возвращаемого значения и результаты функции, ничему не присваиваются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
def func(x):
    if x == 'J' or x == 'Q' or x == 'K':
        x = 10
    elif x == 'A':
        x = 11
```

которая возвращает значение `None`, используйте

```
def func(x):
    if x in 'JQK':      # тот-же самое, но более Питоническое
        x = 10
    elif x == 'A':
        x = 11
    return x
```

Эта функция возвращает `x`, которое вы хотите `применить`, и так вместо

```
func(player_deck)
func(second)
```

используйте просто

```
player_deck = func(player_deck)
second = func(second)
```

Тогда в переменных  `player_deck`  и `second` будут целые числа и в команде

```
player_deck + =second
```

уже не будет ошибки.